# Using Lambdas with Comparator in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

My compiler is telling me: "Expecting member declaration" when making a lambda for comparator.

```
Collections.sort(activities, object: Comparator<ResolveInfo> { a, b ->
    var pm = activity!!.packageManager
    return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(
        a.loadLabel(pm).toString(),
        b.loadLabel(pm).toString())
    })
```

I am not sure that I am writing this lambda properly and would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are combining anonymous class with lambdas, use either:

```
Collections.sort(activities, object : Comparator<ResolveInfo> {
        override fun compare(a: ResolveInfo, b: ResolveInfo): Int {
            var pm = activity!!.packageManager
            return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(
                a.loadLabel(pm).toString(),
                b.loadLabel(pm).toString()
            )
        }
    })
```

or

```
Collections.sort(activities, Comparator<ResolveInfo> { a, b ->
        val pm = applicationContext.packageManager
        String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(
            a.loadLabel(pm).toString(),
            b.loadLabel(pm).toString()
        )
    })
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. Mind if I ask why that doesn't require a return keyword?

Comment: @Lester in Kotlin, the last expression of a lambda is automatically returned